# re-binding issue tkinter/CTklistbox

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm facing a perplexing issue that's beyond my current skill level, and I'm hoping for some expert insight. In my project, I'm struggling with managing multiple listboxes, each with distinct select events. Oddly, regardless of whether a specific class is instantiated, selecting an item in any listbox triggers the event linked to the first-created listbox. This behavior persists even though it seems like a fundamental error in my part.

I've spent considerable time troubleshooting but to no avail. It seems like there might be some underlying issue that I'm not equipped to solve. That's where I hope you, the brilliant minds of this community, can come in.

To clarify the situation:

ListBoxA(CTkListbox) is in class A with its unique on_click function.
ListBoxB(CTkListbox) is in class B, also with its own on_click function.
Despite ListBoxA not being active (its parent class isn't even instantiated), selecting an item in ListBoxB – which is entirely out of scope – somehow triggers the function connected to ListBoxA.

This behavior is baffling and is a significant roadblock in my project. Any insights, advice, or potential solutions would be greatly appreciated. I'm eager to learn and resolve this issue, and your help could be a turning point.

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise!

The code:

```
self.listbox = ListBoxA(self, command=self.on_listbox_select)
```

```
class ListBoxA(CTkListbox):
    def __init__(self, master, command=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        self.command = command
        self.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.on_listbox_select)

    def on_listbox_select(self, event):
        if self.command:
            self.command(event)
```

Thus far naming and separation is ruled out.

Bind related functions in the the CTkListbox class. (unbind added by myself)

```
def bind(self, key, func):
    super().bind_all(key, lambda e: func(self.get()), add="+")

def unbind(self, key):
    super().unbind_all(key)
```

Use of the follwing code removed the connection to ListBoxA, but did not succesfully re-bind.

```
self.unbind("<<ListboxSelect>>")
self.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.on_listbox_selects)
```

Providing self.get function for context:

```
    def get(self, index=None):
        """get the selected value"""
        if index is not None:
            if str(index).lower() == "all":
                return list(item.cget("text") for item in self.buttons.values())
            else:
                index = list(self.buttons.keys())[int(index)]
                return self.buttons[index].cget("text")
        else:
            if self.multiple:
                return (
                    [x.cget("text") for x in self.selections]
                    if len(self.selections) > 0
                    else None
                )
            else:
                return self.selected.cget("text") if self.selected is not None else None
```

Thus far naming and separation is ruled out. Unbind and re-bind sequence did not work.

Comment: I've never actually used CTk, but in plain Tkinter, the default behavior of listboxes is a bizarre mode where the list selection is tied to the system clipboard, and therefore only one list can have a selection at a time.  Selecting anything from a different list would clear the selection in the current list.  The fix is to specify `exportselection=False` on the widgets.